# How do I make my TTS stop speaking when a button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

How do I make my Text-To-Speech stop speaking? Right now, my TTS will start speaking when I launch my application, but I'm trying to make it stop speaking when a button on my Main Activity is pressed.

I have tried creating an onStop() method and using .stop, but to no avail.

May I please get some help on this issue?

Comment: Show your stop code

Comment: i'm new at this, so i'm not sure if this is even correct. MainTTS is my TextToSpeech object.

public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (btnSpeak.isPressed()) {
            MainTTS.stop();
        }
    }

Comment: That's way off I'm afraid. You need to read a tutorial on handling button `onClick` listeners and then simply use `mainTTS.stop()`

Comment: noted, that helped alot. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of this ...

```
stopSpeakingButton.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
String toSpeak = " ";


textToSpeech.speak(
toSpeaks,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
});
```

As you gave us no code this a concept , not the most beautiful solution but will work if you adjust for your use case, the idea is to make it read string with onny a space in it!